# Replication Conflict detection by custom column

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am going to setup Merge replication as Bidirectional.
As you know in merge replication, conflict detect by rowguid and it makes 
problem for me.

When the subscriber create a row for example third row and publisher also create third row, in the time of sync publisher remove record of subscriber because of conflict, but I need that it doesn't detect third row as conflict according to value of other column, is it possible?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following link explain about my question well:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/execute-business-logic-during-merge-synchronization?view=sql-server-2017 .